# data passed from view does not remain after post back

Tags: html, razor, model-view-controller, model, postback

I am unable to find a solution for this as I think this is a bug, or maybe I am not seeing something I should have.

I am passing a model from controlled to view as strongly typed data. However, only one parameter is bugged, it clears it's data after post-back.[image]
When I click Search..
[image]
You can see here, the date from Closed Time is still there, but the text from Cut Off time has gone. The date you see at the end is the value of `@Model.CutOffTimeFrom - @Model.CutOffTimeTo` just to see if the data was cleared or deleted, but it's not, it's just the display on the EditorFor was removed.

I also tried this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35131635/mvc5-lost-value-in-textbox-after-submit), using `<input>` tag but it's still the same output.

Below is my model:

```
[AssertThat("CutOffTimeFrom <= CutOffTimeTo", ErrorMessage = "Date To should be greater than Date From")]
    [RequiredIf("CutOffTimeFrom != null", ErrorMessage = "Date From is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? CutOffTimeFrom { get; set; }

    [RequiredIf("CutOffTimeTo != null", ErrorMessage = "Cut Off Time From is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? CutOffTimeTo { get; set; }
```

and here is the view:

```
<div>
     @*<input type="date" name="CutOffTimeFrom" value="@Model.CutOffTimeFrom" class="form-control input-sm" />-<input type="date" name="CutOffTimeTo" value="@Model.CutOffTimeTo" class="form-control input-sm" />*@
     @Html.EditorFor(m => m.CutOffTimeFrom, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm" } }) - @Html.EditorFor(m => m.CutOffTimeTo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm" } })
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CutOffTimeFrom, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CutOffTimeTo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

All other fields works just fine. Only Cut Off time is being cleared, although it satisfies the search criteria, value is still passed on the model, but it's just not displayed on the view.

Anyone encountered this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thoroughly checked the differences of each element, property, parameter and saw one difference, the date format. Saw the bug upon checking inspect element of each `EditorFor` and saw they were different dates, `2019/02/08` and `02/08/2019`, where the latter is wrong.

Changed it from:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

To:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

Probably the `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` is unable to render 02/08/2019 that's why it doesn't repopulate the form.

Answer (score 0):

Can we see the Controller handling this, because it might happen that its not model binding